# Is there a global touch status in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, touch

As its easy to listen to touch events in WPF, is there a way to tell if the user currently touching the screen or not ?

Comment: The answers in this thread are likely more relevant to your requirements but there's also an interop solution ([GetLastInputInfo](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetLastInputInfo.html)) if you need to know when the last time there was *any* input (keyboard touched, mouse moved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [AreAnyTouchesOver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.areanytouchesover) on any UIElement… including Window.  `Window.AreAnyTouchesOver` will tell you if the user is touching your window.  There is not a WPF API to know if the user is touching another appplication.

Comment: I tried it, but, it didn't work, what worked is AreAnyTouchesOver, so what's the difference between Within and Over in both APIs ?!

Comment: whoops that's what I meant (and what I linked to)  AreAnyTouchesCapturedWithin will tell you if the Capture method has been called on any touches

Answer (score 2):

Yes. WPF 4 even supports MultiTouch

There are some nice examples on [llobo's msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/tags/multitouch/)

And there is [some samples from PDC 09](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=0d695ca64e3fb0c5&resid=D695CA64E3FB0C5!259&id=D695CA64E3FB0C5!259) here.